How to use MediatR in order to navigate between views in avalonia ui
I want to use the MediatR to navigate between views in avalonia ui, I have looked on the web didn't find much information and the avalonia documentation doesn't contain any info either.

I need help, I want to navigate between two views one titled AdminPageView and the other is UserPageView
Thanks
